# windows xp to linux?

Tags: system-installation

I am completely a novice at computers please can anyone provide basic easy to follow instructions of how to install ubuntu on my elderly Toshiba laptop currently running windows xp. And is ubuntu my best option? Thankyou

Comment: Try searching "how to go from windows xp to ubuntu" On either [Google](http://www.google.com), [Bing](http://bing.com) or [Duck Duck Go](http://duckduckgo.com)?

Comment: @Tim please link the person to the right things via an answer or a link onsite; the search terms you recommend don't answer the question very well at all.

Comment: @Jorge OK, I guess because I search for ubuntu a lot on Google it shows me personalised results? I will try using Duck Duck Go when redirecting so they see the same results.

Comment: How old is the laptop? Edit your answer to provide some specs.

Comment: Look at this question before you start to download or install anything to check your laptop's hardware against the minimal systems requirements: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). For <=2GB RAM download the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it would would probably be better to run a lighter version on an older laptop. I just installed Lubuntu on an older dell. Much more just for the basics. Ubuntu 32bit may also run depending on specs. 
   There are plenty of tutorials online on how to download and install. But simply, you choose one you would like. Download the file. Obtain a 4 gig flash drive. Use a LiveUSB program to load the linux file to the flash drive, also making it bootable. Then run on pc you want to change, and mainly follow directions. Any problems, leave a question :)